# unique_ptr creation clarification

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

This is with XCode C++ language dialect c++1y. Help me understand unique_ptr:

```
//1

    auto ouput2 = make_unique<standard::Algorithm>(AlgorithmFactory::create("YamlOutput",
                                                                               "filename", outputFilename));

//2

    unique_ptr<standard::Algorithm> output(standard::AlgorithmFactory::create("YamlOutput",
                                                                                  "filename", outputFilename));
```

1 fails with build with "Semantic Issue: Allocating an object of abstract class type 'essentia::standard::Algorithm", but 2 succeeds.

I [read](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) that these two are equivalent, so how come one succeeds and the other doesn't?

I look at the source for AlgorithmFactory::create() it returns a BaseAlgorithm* depending on the string input. Not really understanding the object hierarchy since standard::Algorithm doesn't seem to have anything to do with BaseAlgorithm (it doesn't extend it).

This is how the documentation for the Essentia library I am using did it except they were using a naked pointer.

Comment: "_I [read](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) that these two are equivalent._" No you didn't. That's not what it says.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two statements aren't equivalent. The difference is:

- Your second version is calling the `unique_ptr` constructor by providing **an existing** raw pointer to the object. It only encapsulates that object pointer in a `unique_ptr`.
- The first version is supposed to be provided with the **constructor arguments** for your object, and it will create the object for you *in a safe way*. It both constructs and encapsulates an object in a `unique_ptr`.

The problem is that your factory **already allocates the object** and returns a raw pointer to it. At that point it doesn't make sense anymore to use `make_unique` since the purpose of that function is to avoid dealing with raw pointers completely, i.e. construct-and-wrap in one go.

You have two options here:

1. Stick to your second version.
2. Change the factory such that it returns a `unique_ptr` by using `make_unique` in its implementation. But it could make sense to also provide a `shared_ptr`-version of the same factory. Something like `createUnique` + `createShared`, and maybe keep the existing `create` which returns a raw pointer. That's a question of code style however.

Answer (score 4):

They aren't equivalent. `make_unique` creates the object whereas `unique_ptr` simply wraps an existing pointer.

Your first line is equivalent to `unique_ptr<standard::Algorithm>(new standard::Algorithm(AlgorithmFactory::create(...)))`. Note the usage of `new` here.

Answer (score 1):

`std::make_unique<T>` forwards its arguments to `T`'s constructor and constructs a new `T`, then makes a `std::unique_ptr<T>` that points to the newly constructed `T`. If `T` is an abstract class then this will definitely fail. Even if `T` were not an abstract class, this would likely not compile since the `AlgorithmFactory::create` function presumably returns a `T*`. On the other hand, `std::unique_ptr<T>`'s constructor takes an argument convertible to `T*`, and there is no problem.